# Android Studio emulator opens but black screen

Tags: android, macos, emulation

I'm new to programming. I've only learned the basics. Right now, I'm trying Android development out with Android Studio. My program simply has a title, and 2 buttons that are supposed to open a URL. There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with my code since nothing is underlined in red, so I don't understand why the layout model isn't showing up in the emulator.

What are some things that affects the emulator from running properly? I tried it on a windows computer and the emulator came after a minute or so. But nothing for the Mac. Anyway to speed up the process?

My code has no errors. Only problem I'm facing is the emulator not running in a timely manner. The app is supposed to open a URL for each of the 2 buttons in the browser.

Running on a Macbook Pro Mid 2010 13" with 8 GB RAM

**************************************Activity Code**********************************************

```
package com.first.bharg.firstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonOnClick();
    }

    public void buttonOnClick(){

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i1 =
                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.yahoo.com"));
                startActivity(i1);
            }
        });

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i2 =
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
                startActivity(i2);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

************************************************Layout******************************************

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="#ffffa157"
    android:focusable="true">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Yahoo"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="107dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="51dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="51dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Google"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="42dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="42dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="First App"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please show your activity code and layout file.

Comment: Try out https://www.genymotion.com/#!/

Comment: Are you using the accelerated x86 AVD or a slower ARM one?

Answer (score 1):

As far as windows concerns, I am afraid there's nothing you can do but wait for the emulator to load everything up. It always takes a lot of time, unless you use your own device (i.e connect your mobile phone to your laptop via USB).

For Mac it's a bit tricky. It's obviously not the only way, but I do suggest you to try another emulator if the one you actually have it's not working properly on it. It's gonna be faster than trying to solve whatever that's going on.

Apparently your code is ok. However if you are new to android I suggest you first get familiar with android activities life cycle before using intents. [Here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) you may find some information related.

I've personally used eclipse's android SDK and it works fine on both OS.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I just don't understand how the setup of Android Studio allows the PC to run the emulator within 1 minute whereas my Mac won't do anything but show a black screen for the emulator. My Macbook Pro is the 13 inch Mid 2010 model. I can confirm that this code showed no errors and ran perfectly. Clicking on one of the buttons prompted the user to choose among the web browsers to open it in and it opened the link. It does what is was intended to do, just not in my personal MBP. The same thing happened in X-Code also when my group partner tried to test run our app on my MBP.

Comment: This behaviour probably has nothing to do with the code but with the software itself. I think that you're experiencing compatibility issues.

Comment: I have experienced exactly what you are experiencing, this has been on emulators and devices. The issue was my computer actually. The computer memory could not handle the launch and the result was a blank screen. I started running Android Studio with no apps open and that fixed it.